# Переклад слова leaderboard

Tags: переклад, from-english

Який усталений переклад цього слова на українську?

> Таблиця лідерів?
>   Рейтинг лідерів?
>   Рейтинг рекордів?
>   Таблиця рекордів?
>   Рейтингова таблиця?
>   ....

Я особисто схиляюся до *таблиця лідерів/рейтинг лідерів*.

Comment: *рейтингова таблиця?*

Comment: @Yola Як один із варіантів.

Comment: @Yola Ви можете додати свій варіант `рейтингова таблиця` у відповіді. Мені цей варіант також подобається і мені здається, що це один із можливих варіантів перекладу(все, звичайно, залежить від контексту).

Comment: Гадаю, що в цьому немає сенсу, бо цей варіант уже представлений в запитанні. І відповідь з одним варіантом виглядатиме куцо.

Comment: Перекласти іншомовне слово іншим іншомовним словом...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У принципі, усі зазначені варіанти мають право на існування. Але вони мають, на мою думку, трішки різне значення.

**[Лідер](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=47771&page=1506)** (якщо брати в потрібному нам значенні) -- це той, хто (зараз) найближчий до перемоги в змаганні; також *лідерами* (у множині) можуть називати відразу декількох найуспіспішніших учасників (тобто, умовно, 1-ше, 2-ге, 3-тє й інші місця, а не лише 1-ше).

**[Рекорд](http://sum.in.ua/s/rekord)** (якщо брати в потрібному нам значенні) -- це нове досягнення в змаганні.

Відповідно, бачу такі можливі відмінності між рейтингом/таблицею лідерів і рейтингом/таблицею рекордів:

- Лідер -- це людина (або інший учасник -- тварина, робот тощо -- але зазвичай усе-таки людина); рекорд -- це її досягнення. Це часто несуттєво (при зазначенні досягнень практично завжди зазначають, хто саме досяг, а при зазначенні найуспішніших учасників майже завжди зрозуміло, у чому їхні досягнення), але все-таки якщо рейтинг/таблиця саме *рекордів*, то логічно, щоб були зазначені, власне, *рекорди*, а не лише люди, що їх поставили. Крім того один учасник може поставити відразу декілька рекордів (спочатку виявився найкращим у тому, а потім -- в іншому; або спочатку зробив великий прорив, а потім раптом перевершив сам себе, зробивши ще більший прорив).
- Лідерів можна визначати, коли змагання ще не завершилося (ті, хто зараз ідуть першими -- то лідери; але вони не обов'язково прийдуть до фінішу першими). Рекорд, власне, теж не обов'язково означає перемогу в змаганні, це просто досягнення -- позитивне (футболіст, що зробив найбільше влучних пасів), нейтральне (футболіст, що найвище підкинув м'яча) чи навіть негативне (футболіст, що найбільше разів викинув м'яч за межі поля) -- але воно не обов'язково приводить до перемоги. (Поставити рекорд -- це факт, який уже ніщо не скасує (хіба що його можуть затьмарити нові, кращі рекорди), а бути лідером -- це стан (навіть якщо він остаточний -- наприкінці чи після завершення змагання).)
- Рекорд зазвичай асоціюється з ширшим часовим проміжком. Хоча можна казати про "рекорд цієї гри/турніру/серії, рекорд цієї зими/року/століття", але зазвичай, якщо немає додаткових пояснень, рекорд -- це те, чого *ніколи* не було до цього. Лідер, здається, такої конотації не має.

Вибирайте, що Вам зручніше, але мені здається, у більшості випадків підійде *рейтинг/таблиця лідерів*.

Щодо *рейтинг* чи *таблиця* -- то тут я не бачу різниці. Згідно з ["Вільним тлумачний словником"](http://sum.in.ua/f/rejtyngh) (хоч це й не "справжній" словник, але тут, мені здається, його тлумачення доволі доречне), рейтинг -- це або окрема оцінка людини/предмата/тощо (але тут це значення не підходить), або список людей/предметів/тощо, упорядкований за їхніми оцінками (а список лідерів майже завжди так і впорядковують). І слово "рейтинг", і слово "таблиця" я вважаю доречнішим застосовувати я у випадку, коли зазначено не лише імена людей, а й якісь величини (час, бали абощо) -- інакше підходитимуть слова "список"/"перелік", але, можливо, не лише вони.

Comment: Я думаю ще може бути просто - рейтинг.

Comment: @improbable А ще рейтинг можна представити у вигляді списку. Гадаю опускати слово таблиця тут не варто.

Answer (score 1):

Жартома можна перекласти як **дошка пошани**.

Фактично єдина відмінність тут це те, що трударів на дошках пошани не так чітко впорядковували.

Answer (score 0):

**Дошка досягнень**, як один з варіантів дошки пошани, але такий що показує певний рейтинг(досягнення).

Comment: Ви могли б чимось підкріпити цю пропозицію? Наприклад, посиланням, де такий варіант уживається? Дякуємо.

Comment: На жаль, не можу представити жодного прикладу. Я випадково натрапив на це обговорення в пошуках перекладу. Попередні коментатори наштовхнули на цей варіант. сс @Sasha

Comment: Ну, наприклад: [1](https://mistoditey.org/doshka-dosyagnen-16/?lang=uk), [2](https://zippo.net.ua/data/files/2020/sodzvinka.pdf), [3](https://nus.org.ua/articles/vchytysya-grayuchy-8-rozvytkovyh-mobilnyh-igor-dlya-ditej/). Просто, на жаль (принаймні, на мій особистий погляд — на жаль), на цьому сайті склалися такі традиції, що короткі відповіді без посилань (навіть якщо вони містять вдалі ідеї чи здаються самодостатніми) часто мінусують.